# D3 not all nodes are updated after replacing data and restarting simulation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to replace data for node visualisation. I was able to add new data but when I am restarting the simulation the nodes which were added are not updating position.

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var width = svg.node().getBoundingClientRect().width;
var height = svg.node().getBoundingClientRect().height;

var data1 =  [{"id":0, "color": "Red"},{"id":1, "color": "Blue"}];
var data2 = [{"id":0, "color": "Cyan"},{"id":1, "color": "Yellow"},{"id":2, "color": "Magenta"}];

/* initialize forces */
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .nodes(data1)
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
        .force("x", d3.forceX(width/2))
        .force("y", d3.forceY(height/2))
        .on("tick", ticked)
        ;

/* create circes based on data1 */
var nodes = svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "nodes")
          .selectAll("circle")
          .data(data1)
          .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("r", 10)
          .style("fill",function (d) { return d.color; } )
          .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
           ;

 /* make transition */ 
  function ticked() 
  {
        nodes
             .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
             .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
             ;
  };

 /* call update */ 
function updateData()
{


  nodes              
      .exit()
      .transition().duration(1000)
      .attr("r", 0)
      .remove()
      ;
  nodes
      .data(data2)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 20)
      .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
      .style("fill",function (d) { return d.color; } )
      ;
      
  nodes
      .attr("r", 20)
      .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
      .style("fill",function (d) { return d.color; } )
      ;

      simulation.nodes(data2)
      .alpha(1).restart()
    ; 
 
    //simulation.force("x").initialize(data2);
    //simulation.force("y").initialize(data2);
    //simulation.force("charge").initialize(data2);
}
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="updateData()">updateData</button> 
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255)"></svg>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I was testing Re-initializing Forces from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57277281/d3-how-to-update-force-simulation-when-data-values-change), but the number of nodes did changed in my case, so this seems to not be a solution for me.

How to update simulation for all nodes from the new dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that removing old nodes does not work correctly. After applying the way of removing below, I managed to get the proper result:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var width = svg.node().getBoundingClientRect().width;
var height = svg.node().getBoundingClientRect().height;

var data1 =  [{"id":0, "color": "Red"},{"id":1, "color": "Blue"}];
var data2 = [{"id":0, "color": "Cyan"},{"id":1, "color": "Yellow"},{"id":2, "color": "Magenta"}];

/* initialize forces */
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .nodes(data1)
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
        .force("x", d3.forceX(width/2))
        .force("y", d3.forceY(height/2))
        .on("tick", ticked)
        ;

/* create circes based on data1 */
var nodes = svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "nodes")
          .selectAll("circle")
          .data(data1)
          .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("r", 10)
          .style("fill",function (d) { return d.color; } )
          .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
           ;

 /* make transition */ 
  function ticked() 
  {
        nodes
             .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
             .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
             ;
  };

 /* call update */ 
function updateData()
{
  svg.selectAll("*").remove();    
      
  nodes = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(data2)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 20)
      .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
      .style("fill",function (d) { return d.color; } )
      ;
      
  nodes
      .attr("r", 20)
      .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
      .style("fill",function (d) { return d.color; } )
      ;

      simulation.nodes(data2)
      .alpha(1).restart()
    ; 
 
    //simulation.force("x").initialize(data2);
    //simulation.force("y").initialize(data2);
    //simulation.force("charge").initialize(data2);
}
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="updateData()">updateData</button> 
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255)"></svg>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Margaryta for the fix. OK, I got it, I need to remove the whole SVG content.

Comment: For anybody else, there is no need to add nodes's attributes second time in updateData()